# Get all of one property from a cell array in one line in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell-array, temporary-objects

I have a cell array (call it `myCells`) with properties `id` and `name`. I desire to select all ID's from the cell array. This is easy in two lines. I can run:

```
tmp=[myCells{:}];
[tmp.id]
```

**Is there a way to toss the intermediate `tmp` variable step?** I would like to do this in one line.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use a cell here? Using a struct would allow you to use `myStruct=struct('id',{1,2});[myStruct.id]` to get all ids

Comment: You could use a function which returns the id's and also checks if in the cell are really structs with the expected fields.

Comment: @Daniel. Unfortunately yes. I add cell entries that might not have all the same properties as other entries which creates `Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures.` errors. It is possible that I _might_ be able to use a normal array of structs but for something this inconsequential I'd probably just concede to using two lines. Thanks!

Comment: @chessofnerd Did it worked for you what I wrote in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The following should do your work

```
extractfield([myCells{:}], 'id')
```